# How can I insert non-repeated records into BigQuery using the bigrquery library?

Tags: r, bigrquery

I'm trying to insert a non-repeated record into BigQuery but keep receiving the error `Array specified for non-repeated field: record.`.

My question is: How can I insert non-repeated records into BigQuery using the [bigrquery](https://github.com/r-dbi/bigrquery) library?

If I have the following schema:

```
bqSchema <- bq_fields(list(
  bq_field(name = "record", type = "RECORD", fields = list(
    bq_field(name = "a", type = "INTEGER"),
    bq_field(name = "b", type = "STRING")
  ))
))
```

And this data frame:

```
df <- tibble(
  record = list(
    a = 1,
    b = "B"
  )
)
```

Inserting the data as below causes the error in BigQuery:

```
bq_perform_upload(bqTableObj, df, fields = bqSchema)
# Array specified for non-repeated field: record
```

I think this is in part because bigrquery [converts the dataframe to JSON](https://github.com/r-dbi/bigrquery/blob/f7eb39de0d5050dac8a3d567eecb2651370a2590/R/old-job-upload.R#L92) with `jsonlite::stream_out()`, but doesn't use the argument `auto_unbox = TRUE`, resulting in arrays, rather than objects. This results in the following newline delimited JSON being sent to BigQuery:

```
{"record": [1]}
{"record": ["B"]}
```

The correct NDJSON that should be sent to BigQuery I believe should be:

```
{"record": {"a": 1, "b", "B"}}
```

Has anyone had this problem before, or have ideas how I can resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

You should try the following where you set mode = "REPEATED" :

```
bqSchema <- bq_fields(list(
  bq_field(name = "record", type = "RECORD", mode = "REPEATED",
           fields = list(bq_field(name = "a", type = "INTEGER"),
                         bq_field(name = "b", type = "STRING")
                         )
           )
 ))
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. However, the format of the data I would like to load is not a repeated field of records. It feels like this answer hides the error rather than solves the problem.